# React Highchart Candlestick not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-highcharts

I'm fairly new to coding with React and I'm trying to build a Candlestick chart using HighChartsReact. However when I add in this functional component, I see an empty div that comes up on my screen. Could you help with what is missing here? Thanks!

I took some code from previous StackOverflow posts describing how I could render a Candlestick chart with ReactHighCharts but no luck.

```
const Candlestick = (props: CandlestickProps) => {
  const [prices, setPrices] = useState(coinPrices);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPrices(props.coin).then((data) => setPrices(data));
  }, [props.coin]);
  Highcharts.theme = {};

  const options = {
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1,
    },
    chart: {
      animation: true,
      type: "candlestick",
    },
    time: {
      useUTC: false,
    },
    title: {
      text: `OHLC Data ${props.coin}`,
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    xAxis: {
      scrollablePlotArea: {
        maxWidth: 1,
      },
      zoomEnabled: true,
      width: "100%",
      range: 10000,
      units: [["hour", [1]]],
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: "PRICE",
        margin: -20,
        style: {
          color: "white",
          fontWeight: 800,
          opacity: 0.7,
        },
      },
    },

    series: [
      {
        step: "center",
        name: "test",
        data: prices.map((price) => [
          price.closeTime,
          price.open,
          price.high,
          price.low,
          price.close,
        ]),
        type: "candlestick",
      },
    ],
  };

  Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

  return (
    <div>
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        constructorType={"stockChart"}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Candlestick;
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by doing
`import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";`
instead of
`import Highcharts from "highcharts";`